# Conditional Logic for Menu in jsp...

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have index.jsp page.

```
 <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">  
    <fieldset style="width: 300px">  
        <legend> Login to App </legend>   
        <table>  
            <tr>  
                <td>User ID</td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="Emp_id" required="required" /></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Password</td>  
                <td><input type="password" name="Pwd" required="required" /></td>  
            </tr> 
           <tr>  
                <td>User Type</td>  
                <td> <select name="usertype">
                <option>Employee</option>
                <option>Manager</option>
                <option>Admin</option>
            </select></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

header.jsp:
when the user logs in with usertype as "Employee" only two menu option must be displayed in the header file of next pages. if usertype is "Admin" or "Manager" then it must show all the four menu options.

```
<body>
    <form name="headerform" action="Get">
    <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${usertype== Employee}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${usertype== Manager}">
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:when test="${usertype== Admin}">
         <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="newemployee.jsp">Add New Employeer</a></li>
            <li><a href="retrieve.jsp">Retrieve TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
        <div class="nav">      
            <ul><li class="container"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/enabling.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="daywise.jsp">DayWise TimeSheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="timesheet.jsp">Weekly TimeSheet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </form>
</body>
```

but from the above code only employee options are visible... I'm using jstl for the first time so please tell me how to do it. or is there any other method to hide the option according to usertype. Index.jsp is different from header.jsp. From index.jsp the usertype value must go to header.jsp of other jsp pages.

Comment: use `eq` tag rather than using `==`.

Comment: @VivekSingh thanks for the reply but I tried... isn't working

Comment: @BalusC I don't know how it is a duplicate.

Comment: use `Employee, Manager and Admin` inside single quotes i.e. `'Employee','Manager' and 'Admin'`

Comment: @VivekSingh thanks a lot... its working!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the employee is visible? Aren't the `otherwise` option?

Your condition is wrong, try to change it in:

```
 <c:when test="${usertype eq 'Employee'}">
```

Comment: thanks fro the quick reply... Yeah i'm sure its not otherwise. whatever first <c:when  is there that menu options are getting on the header

Comment: Have you tested the value of usertype? (Is my simple way that I use to debug in this case)

Comment: yes... I have checked its showing correct usertype